# Anonymous meeting join - Skype for Business online

Tags: skype-for-business, skypedeveloper

I am trying to make the anonymous join to a meeting work using the samples at

https://github.com/OfficeDev/skype-docs/tree/master/Skype/WebSDK

I managed a running instance of samples against localhost IIS and most of the functionality seem to work fine except above.  Note that I am authenticating against Azure AD / Office 365.

I did encounter few issues which I worked around. For ex, I encountered the "Service does not allow a cross domain request from this origin" which I temporarily patched using a fiddler filter to remove X-Ms-Origin header.

Before I spend too much time on it, I would like to know if this feature would work in Skype for business online (or is just for on premise). Depending on that I might have to take a different approach (or even consider on premise instance).

The latest error I now get is "The web ticket is invalid."  while accessing

```
https://webdir2a.online.lync.com/Autodiscover/AutodiscoverService.svc/root/oauth/user?originalDomain=xxx.onmicrosoft.com
```

Request:

```
GET https://webdir2a.online.lync.com/Autodiscover/AutodiscoverService.svc/root/oauth/user?originalDomain=xxx.onmicrosoft.com HTTP/1.1
Host: webdir2a.online.lync.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:51.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/51.0
Accept: application/json
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Referer: https://webdir2a.online.lync.com/Autodiscover/XFrame/XFrame.html
X-Ms-Namespace: internal
X-MS-Correlation-Id: 2096091305
Client-Request-Id: WebSDK/2096091305
X-Ms-SDK-Version: SkypeWeb/0.4.436 master sdk-samples/1.0.0
X-Ms-SDK-Session: f64bc747722c5
Authorization: Bearer cwt=AAIDHAEFAAAAAAAFF....uhmA
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
```

Response

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: text/html
X-Ms-diagnostics: 28032;source="BLU2A00EDG01.infra.lync.com";reason="The web ticket is invalid."
X-MS-Server-Fqdn: BLU2A00EDG01.infra.lync.com
X-MS-Correlation-Id: 4f9f39ed-f990-4e0f-a977-4434dd4c1e9f
client-request-id: WebSDK/2096091305
x-ms-client-request-id: 150115bb-ce84-4e0a-9560-3ed9ea215f11
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Date: Wed, 08 Mar 2017 14:18:50 GMT
Content-Length: 1208
```

While not exact, it appears it is very close to what is explained in the following link.

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/poptart/2015/01/28/ucwa-with-directors-or-multiple-pools/

I would really appreciate some clarifications here

Raj

Comment: Which authentication did you use to login to SfB Online?

Answer (score 0):

Are you having problems authenticating an end-user against Skype for Business Online, creating the anonymous meeting URL, or something else ...?  The auth process for Skype for Business Online is different than the on-premise version.

Comment: I am able to authenticate the end user against Skype for business and create the meeting url.  It is just that I am NOT able to join the meeting anoymously  (the errors in original post comes up).    Intrestingly, in the github samples for Skype for business, the sample to anoymous join is excluded from build  (which makes me suspect this is not fully supported in non premise installations)